# A way to extract layer sets from PSD files without Photoshop?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, software-rec, extract, psd

Are there any tools for (in order of preference) Mac, Linux, or Windows to extract images per layer set from a PSD file, without using Photoshop? I had a web designer send me a PSD file containing multiple pages, and each page is apparently in a layer set, and GIMP cannot handle these -- it can't understand layer groupings.

A command line tool, a rinky-dink Windows tool...anything will work (of course, free is preferable), so long as it does not leave watermarks or anything of the sort, and works well.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/471458/399650

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to download the Photoshop trial version from Adobe.

Answer (score 4):

ImageMagick [supports](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#psd) PSD layers and can extract them to separate image files. But I like Joe Internet's answer if you only have to do this once or twice.

Answer (score 2):

GIMP does read the layers (I use GIMP 2.6 sometimes) altough it doesn't understand layer properties made in photoshop (like borders and shadows) or folders (groupings) which are made in photoshop.

[Paint Shop Pro](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/us/en/Product/1184951547051#tabview=tab0) opens PSD files too

Comment: GIMP does not work well exporting psd files. I have tried this many times...

Answer (score 0):

Bring out the [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)

The GIMP will read PSD files with layers and write back in any format that it supports, which are many.

Comment: My problem is with layer sets, though. It seems GIMP can't read those. From my research, it seems support for that is coming in 2.8.

Comment: Can you get a 2.8 beta?

Comment: No GIMP does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use specialized tools for it.

For example, you can check Aspose PSD Extract App. It doesn't use Photoshop and this app is free.

https://products.aspose.app/psd/extract

But there are can be some differences in rendering